# HOw to calculate correlation between different groups using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, attributes, correlation

I have a tables in SQL  and I want to calculate correlation coefficient corr() between id=1 and id=2 based on Norms column . Any hints, please? and 2)  how can I find a correlation between “norms” of id=1 and id=2 during the dates in which they overlap?

| id | Date _time | Norms | value | Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 00:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 01:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-11-30 02:00:00 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | . | . | . | . |
| 1 | 2020-12-2 23:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-11-14 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-11-14 01:00:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-11-14 02:00:00 | -1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | 2020-01-06 23:00:00 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

*norms= avg - values

Comment: can you  define what you mean by "correlation between two “norms" ? give us some  examples for your desired output

Comment: I changed my question a little bit @eshirvana

Comment: so you want to calculate correlation any norm of id =2 with any norm of id =2 ? is that correct?

Comment: I think I need correlation of group 1 and group 2 .. But I would appriciate it if you kindly tell me both of them (group 1 and2) and ( any norm of id =2 with any norm of id =2 )

Comment: when you group all norms of one id , how would you consider your two points , is it going to be average of norms in each group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate correlation coefficient of every norm of combination of two groups :

```
select corr(t1.norms , t2.norms) 
from youratble t1
inner join yourtable t2
  on t1.id = 1 
  and  t2.id = 2
```

Comment: they are just alias for your table names

Comment: Thank you very much , And I have a another question. If I had id=1 to id =20 and I had a different view that specified the each two ids that were the closest  to each other(In terms of there locations). Then how could I calculate correlation for each two id s that were closest to each other ina new view ?

Comment: @feriamen you have to provide more information , make another question and provide sample data and desired output as well